# python random sampling based on a distribution

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution

Before going to the topic, let's first take a look on the python's default sampling method,

```
>>> import random
>>> c=[1,2,3,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,109,110,111,112,113,114]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[103]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[3]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[3]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[2]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[3]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[2]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[106]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[3]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[105]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[110]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
[103]
>>> random.sample(c,1)
```

From the [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/random.py) we can easily see what it actually does (below is the major portion of the code from the link),

```
selected = set()
selected_add = selected.add
for i in xrange(k):
    j = _int(random() * n)
    while j in selected:
        j = _int(random() * n)
        selected_add(j)
        result[i] = population[j]
```

This sampling method has randomly chosen an index. In case of that, there is a chance that a very non-likely population member got selected. Say for example `1` in the above example.

But let's concentrate on a more realistic scenario. Let's assume you have 16 number which represents the frequency of some label from `0-15`.

`freq array = [1, 2, 3, 100, 100, 100, 102, 102, 102, 100, 99, 50, 20, 1, 2, 3]`

index of each position represents the label type. Like from the above list we can say that the total number of population on label 0 is 1, the total number of population on label 3 is 100, the total number of population of label 2 is 3 etc.

now if you want to select 5 members from the population, can we generate a new list which tells that I should take `X` number of members from label `Y` based on some distribution. (For the time being, let's assume normal distribution),

A sample: (maybe not the answer)

`new_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

it means we should take 1 member from label 4-7.

So maybe the question is well ask in the following manner,

How to sample members from a population based on some Normal distribution and population frquency. (For the time being, let's strict it to Normal Distribution)

I searched for functions in both `python.random` and `np.random` library but could not get anything useful. Your idea or suggestion is highly appreciated and if possible code also.

Comment: `np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)` gives you a sample of `size = 100` from a normal distribution with `mu = 0`, `sigma = 1`.

Comment: @Graipher thanks for your comment. yes, it does. But does it solve the problem that is mentioned in the problem? So now the question becomes, how can we change the `mu and sigma` based on the `freq_array`

Comment: Is that your question? Then you should say so.

Comment: @Graipher Sorry that it was not clear. But the whole explanation is given in the example. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

using numpy you have numpy.random.normal (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) that allows you to generate numbers from a normal distribution.

for example to generate 100 random number from a normal distribution with mean 5.0 and standard deviation 1.0 you use:

```
numpy.random.normal(loc=5.0,scale=1.0,size=100)
```

A lot of other distributions are available here the list:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

Comment: Can you give an idea how to calculate the `mean` and `standard deviation based` on the frequency of the population for each label stated above?

Comment: @Maruf Use [`numpy.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.average.html): `values = np.arange(len(freq_array)); mu = np.average(values, weights=freq array)`. The std dev is a bit harder: `sigma = np.sqrt(np.average((values-mu)**2, weights=freq array))`.